# Is there a way to draw pieces of the image on 2d canvas without transparent parts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, bitmap, html5-canvas, crop

I would like to draw **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR1tk.png)** image on canvas without the transparent parts. The principle of my rendering is that I crop small images from a large image using the [createImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CreateImageBitmap) method and store them in an array. I then render them on the canvas one by one. The problem is that it also unnecessarily draws the transparent parts. So if I log my array I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSCre.png). Since my map is 10x10 tiles it results in 100 images (of which 96 are useless). Instead, I would like to save only 4 images.

Not only that it messes up my performance but I have more reasons why it bothers me. Is there a way to solve this problem?

**My code so far:**

```js
(async () => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = "./img/obstacles.png";
    await img.decode();

    let tiles = [];
    let tileWidth = 32;
    let tileHeight = 32;

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        let x = i % 10;
        let y = Math.floor(i / 10);

        let bmp = await createImageBitmap(img, x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight); // index.js:13

        tiles.push({
            bmp,
            x,
            y
        })
    }

    console.log(tiles)

    const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    canvas.width = 320;
    canvas.height = 320;

    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        tiles.forEach((tile) => {
            ctx.drawImage(tile.bmp, tile.x * tileWidth, tile.y * tileHeight);
        })

        // requestAnimationFrame(draw)
    }
    draw();

})();
```

Comment: You would have to get the pixel data of the tiles so that you can test them, which is often an expensive operation (plus the CORS errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is to prepare your asset correctly, so here that would mean having only the 3 unique sprites in your atlas:

[image: OP's atlas without the transparent slots]

Then you can use your simple loop to get these as separate objects.

However it's not uncommon to have sprites of different sizes in the same atlas, in such a case, your simple loop won't do. Instead, you should prepare a coordinates dictionary (e.g as a JSON file, or embedded directly in your js), with all the coordinates of each sprites.

Most spritesheet generating tools will produce this for you.

Here is an example where I just added one big sprite to the atlas:

[image: Atlas of 3 small sprites and one big]

```js
(async () => {
    // If you are same-origin, it's better to fetch as a Blob
    // and create your ImageBitmap from the Blob
    // Here we aren't, so we have to go through an <img>
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7w1C.png";
    await img.decode();
    document.body.append(img);
    // We hardcode the coords of each sprite
    const map = [
      // [x, y, w, h]
      [0,  0, 32, 32],
      [0, 32, 32, 32],
      [0, 64, 32, 32],
      [32, 0, 96, 96],
    ];
    const tiles = [];
    
    for (const [x, y, w, h] of map) {
        const bmp = await createImageBitmap(img, x, y, w, h);
        tiles.push({
            bmp,
            x,
            y
        })
    }

    console.log(tiles)

    const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    canvas.width = 320;
    canvas.height = 320;

    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let m = 0;
    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        m = (m + 0.005) % 0.5;
        const margin = m + 1;
        tiles.forEach((tile) => {
            // we add some margin to show these are separate bitmaps
            ctx.drawImage(tile.bmp, tile.x * margin, tile.y * margin);
        })

        requestAnimationFrame(draw)
    }
    draw();

})().catch(console.error);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100px !important }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: To show me how to use the atlas properly, your advice is very useful. But if I wanted to place my sprites as in my previous picture, would I need to add to my loop the exact coordinates where these pieces should be located or does it have something to do with the json/js map you mentioned?

Comment: I must admit I don't really get why you'd place your sprites like this; but if you really wanted then yes, either you store the 4 sprites coords like I did, or you could even just store the indexes where your sprites are in your loop.

Comment: `I must admit I don't really get why you'd place your sprites like this`
Well.. I want to make 3 layers consisting of images where each will have its function. This was a sample of the third layer (where I would like to check the collisions between the player (on the second layer) and the objects). Therefore, I need to specify the exact position of the images on each layer.